# What is the correct way to use d3.js exit functions with nested lists

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Part 1** - Fixed see update below. Part 2 still needs a solution.

I have a problem getting d3 version 3 to work with enter, update, append, exit in the way I want it to for nested lists. I'd like to have a HTML structure like this:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li> 1
    <ul>
      <li>Shawn Allen</li>
      <li>Mister</li>
      <li>Mike Bostock</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> 2
    <ul>
      <li>Shawn Allen2</li>
      <li>Mister2</li>
      <li>Mike Bostock2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I'd like the data to have a structure similar to this:

```
var innerlistdata = [
  {key: "h1", data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
  {key: "h2", data: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
];
```

When items are removed from the data array I want the exit function to be able to animate the removal of the items, e.g.:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  innerlistdata[1].data.pop();
  innerlistdata[1].data.pop();
  innerlistdata[1].data.pop();
  innerlistdata[1].data.pop();
  update(innerlistdata);
}, 6000);
```

Additionally, when the parent items are removed I'd like the exit function to remove a full subsection again animated, e.g.:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  innerlistdata.pop();
  update(innerlistdata);
}, 12000);
```

I've read a number of articles online and similar stackoverflow problems including: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/ and the comments by mbostock here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/5AxgsKK31EA but cannot get it to work the way I want it to.

I think I am close to the solution I need but feel like there's some nuance I've missed and that is why I am asking here.

I have created and example, showing the problem, in the following codepen: https://codepen.io/misterfitzy/pen/JMYojw

Even the child "key" function has the expected behaviour i.e.

```
var child = parent
    .selectAll("li")
      .attr('class', 'update')
      .data(function(d, i) { return d.data; }, function(d, i) {return d;});
```

causes the items in the data array to be "entered" and the initial text "exits" appropriately.  When the subitems are removed from the data array the exit function gracefully fades out the items.

Everything works as I expect it to apart from transition of the exit function of the parent function.  The items disappear immediately rather than being animated. This tells me that the parent exit function but the animation doesn't.  Any ideas?

UPDATE:
The solution in part 1 work it turns out that using 'color' as a transition property is a bad idea as it doesn't style the child elements.  Using opacity instead has the desired effect:

```
  parent.exit()
    .transition()
    .attr("class", "exit")
    .duration(5000)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove();
```

**Part 2:**

I also tried a solution where the initial list is empty and the nested list is created based on the data entirely.  The initial list:

```
<ul id="list2">
</ul>
```

Initial data:

```
var innerlistdata = [
  {key: "h1", data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
  {key: "h2", data: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
];
```

Codepen for this example:

https://codepen.io/misterfitzy/pen/xpVRWx

This time the items are correctly created and "entered" appropriately.  However, I cannot figure out how to get the child exit function to fire at all.  I suspect it's to do with my selections but am at a loss.

In my example I tried a custom key function, it's a bit hacky but should be good enough to identify child items without using 0, 1, 2, 3, ... etc.

```
function(d, i) {return "key" + d + "" + i;}
```

This just creates keys based on the value and index in the 2d array. Pretty much guaranteed to be unique and not a simple index. Pretty crappy but should be good enough for this example.

However, when the items are popped off the child exit function doesn't fire.  When the parent exit function fires it removes all child elements showing that my key function is most likely broken.

When I print the key values the first time the page is loaded I get the following keys:

```
// Parents
{key: "h1", data: Array(6)}
{key: "h2", data: Array(6)}

// Children
child: key00
child: key11
child: key22
child: key33
child: key44
child: key55
child: key60
child: key71
child: key82
child: key93
child: key104
child: key115
```

When I pop the items, as in example 1, I get the following keys from the parent:

```
{key: "h1", data: Array(6)}
0
1
2
3
4
5
{key: "h2", data: Array(2)}
6
7
8
9
10
11
{key: "h1", data: Array(6)}
```

And no keys for the children.  This is a clear indication I've messed up the data binding but I have no idea why or how.

So to all you d3.js people out there, would you mind taking a look at my examples and giving me a push in the right direction please?  I am pulling my hair out over this one!

Thanks!

Comment: I updated the post to say that part 1 has a solution.  Part 2 is still a problem.  I will move it to it's own question shortly and close this one.